# Downloading files to downloads folder in android >=11 (flutter)

Tags: android, flutter, download, dio, storage-access-framework

I am using the dio package to download a pdf file. How can I store it in the downloads folder and subsequently perform operations on it like view and delete? It seems it is only possible through the SAF framework, but I'm unable to find any plugin which can do the same with minimal use of document tree and persisted uri permissions.

I have tried the shared_storage plugin, but it opens the document tree for every operation. PersistedUris doesn't work, and only the user has the permissions to create the a new folder with the app's name in the downloads directory.

Comment: You can put it in the classical way in the public Download folder. No SAF needed. Unclear which problem you have. Where is the code? I have no idea why flutter or dio would behave different.